# Reduce Jhipster React and spring boot build time

Tags: reactjs, typescript, spring-boot, gitlab-ci, jhipster

I'm working on a full stack application generated with Jhipster using React with typescript and Spring Boot. Gradle and npm is used as build tools for `backend` and `frontend`.

The project is built using the following command :-

`./gradlew -Pprod clean bootJar`.

This command takes around 2 minutes in my local which seems alright. But the same when run through Gitlab `CI/CD` pipeline takes around 6 minutes. I noticed there is a type checking service which is running that takes the maximum time in the Build stage of the pipeline :-

```
Starting type checking service...
<=====--------> 45% EXECUTING [53s]
> :webpack
```

Any info on how to reduce this build time would be appreciated.

Comment: The VM running your CI is slower than your dev system.

Comment: Try not to clean everything. It is not needed. Dependending on your gitlab ci configuration there gradle caches kick in (e.g. build on same branch can reuse already builded artifacts from runs before).